# Embed shared libs in Java Applets

Tags: java, deployment, applet, java-native-interface

Is it possible to embed linux shared libs (.so) in Java applets?

I know that I can call JNI code from applets (privileged only), but is it possible embed these libs inside the applet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..is it possible embed these libs inside the applet?

No.  Natives should be inside the root path of a separate Jar.  There should be separate Jars for OS X, *nix and Windows.  Then use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy the lot and reference each Jar containing natives in an OS specific `resource` section of the JNLP launch file - so each OS only downloads the type of natives that it requires.